# Use stored procedure when getting blob at spring mvc

Tags: spring

I wanted to learn how to use Stored Procedure when inserting BLOB data on my MSSQL Table.

```
final File blobIn = new File("spring2004.jpg");
final InputStream blobIs = new FileInputStream(blobIn);
final File clobIn = new File("large.txt");
final InputStream clobIs = new FileInputStream(clobIn);
final InputStreamReader clobReader = new InputStreamReader(clobIs);
jdbcTemplate.execute(
  "INSERT INTO lob_table (id, a_clob, a_blob) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
  new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobhandler) {                         (1)
      protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) 
          throws SQLException {
        ps.setLong(1, 1L);
        lobCreator.setClobAsCharacterStream(ps, 2, clobReader, (int)clobIn.length());    (2)
        lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 3, blobIs, (int)blobIn.length());           (3)
      }
  }
);
blobIs.close();
clobReader.close();
```

The spring framework 2.5 documentation uses jdbc template.  But this is a NO-NO in my case.
I hope somebody could share their insights on how to do insert and retrieve the data as
an inputstream.

I have been trying to google for the answer but not enough resource on this can be found.

Comment: What's wrong with `JdbcTemplate`?

Comment: Hi Skaffman,

Having a stored procedure gives me more flexibility than raw jdbc template.  I can perform server side query without the need for another round trip from client to server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Spring + JPA with a native query or with JpaDaoSupport.

There are good answers in the following links:

- [Native query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886447/628006)
- [JpaDaoSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17082717/628006)