# Invoke stored procedure using JPA (JpaDaoSupport) in java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to invoke/call a stored procedure in java using JPA API. We are extending our class to use JpaDaoSupport class. I have tried invoking Call/ begin stored proc method but its not working as expected. Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm taking the liberty to add the "Spring" tag since I couldn't find any other well known library having such a named class

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring's [JpaDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/JpaDaoSupport.html) then you can call your stored procedure two ways:

1) via [SimpleJdbcCall](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) which you are passing the datasource and it is using underneath [jdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to make the call (an example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/calling_stored_procedure.htm))

2) implementing as an inner class the abstract [StoredProcedure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html) and therefore encapsulating all the stored procedure logic (an example [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/spring-framework-tutorial-call-stored-procedures-from-java.html)).